# Jquery get element in header json array

Tags: jquery, json

Im trying to fill my pagination with the data i get in the servers response header:

```
console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Pagination'));
```

returns:

```
{"total":12184,"total_pages":1016,"first_page":true,"last_page":false,"previous_page":null,"next_page":2,"out_of_bounds":false,"offset":0}
```

Now i tried to use this data:

```
                var headers = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Pagination');
                    var options = {
                        bootstrapMajorVersion: 3,
                        size: "small",
                        currentPage: headers["next_page"],
                        totalPages: headers["total_pages"]
                    }
```

I dont understand why but:

```
                        headers["next_page"]
                        totalPages: headers["total_pages"]
```

Return `undefined`! What do i wrong? Thanks

Comment: make a jsfiddle if possible .

Comment: i did for you and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/n4xKx/

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that `xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Pagination')` returns a string that you must parse before get info as a Json object.

Comment: @francadaval i think your right! Can you post it as a answer?

Comment: Just done! Please check it as the right answer. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var headers = JSON.parse(xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Pagination'));
```

to transform it from `string` to an object so you can get `headers["next_page"]` and `headers["total_pages"]`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your given data

> console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Pagination'));
>   {"total":12184,"total_pages":1016,"first_page":true,"last_page":false,"previous_page":null,"next_page":2,"out_of_bounds":false,"offset":0}

it should be not

```
headers["next_page"]
totalPages: headers["total_pages"]
```

but

```
headers.next_page
totalPages: headers.total_pages
```

JSON is js object not array. Hope this helps.

Comment: In JavaScript, `headers["next_page"]` equals `headers.next_page`: see http://jsfiddle.net/ftKHa/.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the response:

```
var headers = JSON.parse(xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Pagination'));
var options = {
    bootstrapMajorVersion: 3,
    size: "small",
    currentPage: headers["next_page"],
    totalPages: headers["total_pages"]
    }
```